# Need to remove ".ytp-pause-overlay" that appear when YouTube Player is paused

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, youtube

I am using a video player called Vimuse (http://codecanyon.cosmo-coder.com/vimuse/youtube.html). I need to find a way to remove the 'related/suggested videos" that appears when a user pauses the video. The culprit is the following two classes: .ytp-expand-pause-overlay .ytp-pause-overlay from YouTube.com's www-player-vflthaDCh.css file. I have tried overwriting the css with display:none, but it will not overwrite it.

Is there another way of doing this using jQuery or JavaScript (I am new with both these, but am willing to try anything)? Or any other suggestions? I am wondering if it is possible to simply remove the .ytp-expand-pause-overlay .ytp-pause-overlay classes completely using jQuery or JS?

The playlist is loaded using a playlistID (not a url) so I cannot add the ?rel=0 to the end of the playlistID to remove the related videos.

Here is the code used to initiate the player:

```
$.fn.vimuse.defaults.autoplay = true;
        var $app = $('#player').vimuse({
            getID3Info: true,
            showPlaylistThumbs: true,
            enableCache: false,
            showFileTypeIcons: false,
            youtubeAPIKey: 'AIzaSyBE0eCj5Y7SAe7pbdorzw2_HJSU_JHYFBT',  // enter your Youtube API Key here
            youtubeFeed: true,
            playlistPosition: 'left',
            youtubeOptions: {
                source: 'playlist',
                playlistID: 'PLfs-w3ltz3MrPDUqxdFus8f7Oj-9659IH',
                limit: 10 // max-limit 50 set by YouTube
            }
        });
```

I tried using this code to remove it, but cannot get it to work:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-pause-overlay ytp-scroll-min")[0].remove();
})();
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, never have. I still need a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the browser, with right-click on an element - let say, one of the suggested videos - , select "Inspect".

This option will open the F12 developer tools (*DevTools, for short*).

Once opened the DevTools, it will show the HTML code in the "Elements" tab. There, expand the nodes that contains the element you want to delete - in this case, the div with that specific class name.

Then, move to the "Console" tab of the DevTools and - using the following line of code, you can modify the element found as you require.

Example:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-pause-overlay ytp-scroll-min")[0].style.display = 'none';
```

or even, deleting the `innerHTML` of the div:

Example:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-pause-overlay ytp-scroll-min")[0].innerHTML = '';
```

Comment: for both I get cannot find property of undefined. do you need to do sth extra to access the content of an iframe?

Comment: @J0hannes in the console of the browser, you have to inspect deeper for "show" the code and then, execute the code lines I added on my answer. As far as I know, there is no other way due to iframe, CORS and domain security restrictions.